# Assign ID of workflow created list to lookup field

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

Hi I'm trying to find a solution to my logic process below, I'm new to workflows.

Current Scenario:

I create itemA in ListA.
Workflow then creates itemB in ListB.
I then open itemA and assign lookupfieldA the ID of itemB

ideal scenario:

I create itemA in ListA.
Workflow then creates itemB in ListB.
Workflow then assigns lookupfieldA of itemA, ID of itemB.

Cheers for any assistance.

Comment: By ID do you mean GUID?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SP Designer 2013 you can type:-

1. Create item (I believe you have already done this, to create itemB in ListB). This will generate a GUID which is saved into a local variable. (check the variable name at RHS of this line)
2. Then type: Update and hit enter key
   This will generate as:-
   Update Item in THIS LIST
   -->  Click on 'this list'

--> Dialog box will popup

--> Choose the ListA

--> Click 'ADD' and choose the 'current item'

--> Set this field 'Choose lookup field'

--> Set the To field value as: Data Source:Workflow variable and parameters

--> Then, choose the local variable that holds the GUID of the 'create' step (from point no. 1).

Let me know if you have any question..

Comment: I attempted this with using both actions. (Update item in list, as well as Set field on current item) In both cases, the value for the look up field was expected to be an integer, and as a result, attempting to use the GUID returned from the created item resulted in "OK" being grayed out. I additionally tried subsequently looking up the new list item based on GUID, and also had no success. See: http://i.imgur.com/Bm5SgFu.png

Answer (score 0):

Solution described by variable, as well as "set field in current item" works fine in a Sharepoint 2010 workflow.